# Apollo React: SSR avoid client refetching data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, apollo, react-apollo

I am using React with Redux and GraphQl using Apollo React client to provide Server Side Rendering. Everything is working fine but I noticed due to configuration the client the Refetching the data again on browser.

**How can I avoid the refetching of data on browser?**

Comment: Are you hydrating the data on the client? You might also want to use the ssrForceFetchDelay option: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#apollo-client

Comment: Ha Right Now i am facing this problem Any solution